# Application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. Authentication error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

[image]

Error while connecting an azure bot to the server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Check the Guest user settings
  Navigate to the  `Azure Active Directory`  in tenant A (Admin) ->  `User settings`  ->  `Manage external collaboration settings`
  set  `Guest users permissions are limited`  to  `No`

[image]

Navigate to the  `Azure Active Directory`  in tenant A (Admin) ->  `Enterprise applications`  ->  `User settings`
set  `Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf`  to  `Yes`.

[image]

Please refer [about the member user and guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions%5D(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions))  and [Solution for the similar issue](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/12/fix-aadsts700016-application-not-found-or-consented-to-by-any-user.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Surprise, surprise the error is actually stating what the problem is. You either try to reach the wrong tenant or your app is not registered.

That being said, where can you find the **Tenant ID**?

Open the **Azure Portal**, then using the search functionality navigate to **Active Directory**. There under **Overview** you should find the **Tenant ID**.

[image]

If you are using **GitHub Actions** and **Terraform** such as myself.
You would need to set the following line in your **.yml** file.

```
env:

  ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID }}
```

There should also be a **secret** named **AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID** in your GitHub repository.

[image]

[image]

[image]